# Crosscompilation cannot find some libraries

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cmake, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile a ROS package for a **Jetson nano** (`aarch64`) using my `x86_64` PC. I am using the [toolchain provided by nvidia](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/downloads#?search=tool%20chain&tx=$product,jetson_tx2,jetson_nano) (GCC Tool Chain for 64-bit BSP). I have been following [this article](https://medium.com/@tahsincankose/cross-compiling-ros-project-for-arm-263642b405ac) for guidance

As the compiler needs binaries from the aarch64 system, I have mounted the nano's `/usr/include` into my build directory's `usr/include`. Here's my build directory hierarchy.

```
.
├── gcc-4.8.5-aarch64   #<cross compiler>
│   └── install
│       ├── aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
│        ...
├── opt                 #<ROS source files from nano>
│   └── ros
│       └── melodic
├── src                 #<test c++ code in here>
│   └── test_cpp
│       └── src
└── usr
    ├── include      #<nano's /usr/include mounted in here>
    └── lib
        └── aarch64-linux-gnu  #<nano's /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu mounted in here>
```

When compiling, I get errors saying the compiler cannot find `crt1.o`, `crti.o` and `libpthread.so.0` libraries.

```
/home/teshan/xcompile/gcc-4.8.5-aarch64/install/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.5/../../../../aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/home/teshan/xcompile/gcc-4.8.5-aarch64/install/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.5/../../../../aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/home/teshan/xcompile/gcc-4.8.5-aarch64/install/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.5/../../../../aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 inside /home/teshan/xcompile
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Before mounting `/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu` and `/usr/include`, I've had errors saying cannot find **Boost** libraries. They have disappeared now since the library files are available in the mounted directories.

However, I have the asked files `crti.o` and `crt1.o` in the mounted directories just like boost library files. So why can’t the compiler find them?

```
$ find -name crti.o -type f
./gcc-4.8.5-aarch64/install/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/crti.o
./usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/crti.o
$ find -name crt1.o -type f
./gcc-4.8.5-aarch64/install/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/crt1.o
./usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/crt1.o
```

I do not have `libpthread.so.0` as asked but have `libpthread.so`. What can I do about this?

```
$ find -name libpthread.so* -type f
./gcc-4.8.5-aarch64/install/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/libpthread.so
./usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so
```

---

**TL;DR**

This is my build script

```
#!/bin/bash

PWD=$(pwd)
export LANG=C
source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash

catkin config --extend ${PWD}/opt/ros/melodic/

catkin build -j8 --cmake-args \
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${PWD}/toolchain.cmake \
-DCMAKE_CROSS_COMPILE_PREFIX=${PWD} \
-DRT_LIBRARY=${PWD}/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/
```

---

Here's my toolchain.cmake

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)

SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${NANO_ROOT_PATH}/gcc-4.8.5-aarch64/install/bin/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${NANO_ROOT_PATH}/gcc-4.8.5-aarch64/install/bin/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-g++)

# Below call is necessary to avoid non-RT problem.
SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE aarch64-linux-gnu)

SET(NANO_ROOT_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})
SET(NANO_MELODIC_PATH ${NANO_ROOT_PATH}/opt/ros/melodic)

SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${NANO_ROOT_PATH} ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX})
SET(COMPILER_ROOT ${NANO_ROOT_PATH}/gcc-4.8.5-aarch64/install)

#Have to set this one to BOTH, to allow CMake to find rospack
#This set of variables controls whether the CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH and CMAKE_SYSROOT are used for find_xxx() operations.
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM BOTH)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)

SET(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${NANO_MELODIC_PATH} ${NANO_ROOT_PATH}/usr)

SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} --sysroot=${NANO_ROOT_PATH}" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} --sysroot=${NANO_ROOT_PATH}" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
SET(CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS} --sysroot=${NANO_ROOT_PATH}" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS} --sysroot=${NANO_ROOT_PATH}" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)

SET(LD_LIBRARY_PATH ${NANO_MELODIC_PATH}/lib)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)

#Skip toolchain trying to build a test program first
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS 1)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS 1)

set(BOOST_ROOT ${NANO_ROOT_PATH}/usr/include/boost)

set(COMPILER_SYSROOT ${COMPILER_ROOT}/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot)
include_directories(BEFORE SYSTEM ${COMPILER_SYSROOT}/usr/include/)
```

Comment: looks like it can't find sysroot..NANO_ROOT_PATH is used before it's set though, that may be a problem

Comment: Holy! So stupid. Let me correct it and try again. Thanks

Comment: No problem, glad to help..If it works i'll put that as the answer ?

Comment: No luck. Apparently, with the `NANO_ROOT_PATH` empty, the path was correct as the relative path or something it seems (still there's a leading `/` but it works the same. Don't know how)

Comment: try replacing --sysroot=${NANO_ROOT_PATH} in the compiler flags with hard paths. About your second question, libpthread.so.0 can be just a symbolic link to libpthread.so

Comment: I will try that and comment here. About `libpthread`, I don't have a `libpthread.so.0` anywhere. Neither in my PC nor in the nano (I searched). Any idea about why it looks for `libpthread.so.0`?

Comment: the libpthread.so should be a symbolic link to a real libpthread.so.(MAJOR VERSION). Maybe one reason your build could fail - it usually causes headaches - is if symbolic links havent been copied. But please see this post for more info about .so versions https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475/how-do-so-shared-object-numbers-work

Comment: CMake has a special variable [CMAKE_SYSROOT](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_SYSROOT.html), which is denoted to contain a sysroot directory. Just assign your `NANO_ROOT_PATH` to that variable, and CMake could be able to pass `--sysroot` option for the compiler/linker automatically. Also, once you assign a directory to `CMAKE_SYSROOT`, there is no needs to add this directory to `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` variable: CMake already treats this directory in this way.